# jQuery code is not implemented second time

Tags: jquery

First time code is implemented right(some elements disappear by click and then appear by one more click + toggleClass). Second time only toggleClass works. Why?

```
   $('.avatar').click(function() {

            $('.avatar').toggleClass("hey");
            $(".changebutton").hide();
                $(".myButton").hide();

                $('.avatar').click(function() {

                $('.avatar').toggleClass("heyback");
            $(".changebutton").show();
                $(".myButton").show();


      });
     });
```

Comment: Don't put event handlers inside other event handlers, that's the issue

Comment: @adeneo how to implement second click handler?

Comment: it would be easy if you post you html too

Comment: Keep a state of click, preferably with a variable, initialise it as false. On click, check if it's true (i.e. not first click) then do set second actions, else do set of first actions *and* set it to true.

Comment: Wait, why do you have two click handlers for the same elements, one inside the other, that's even worse

Comment: @noob too much code, which is not related

Comment: Maybe you can do this -> http://jsfiddle.net/w91u1veb/1/

Comment: @adeneo, that was my initial idea, but wasn't sure what OP wanted with that `heyback` thing, so added conditionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking a wrong approach. Your code is assigning a new click listener every time you click that avatar. Consider something like this:

```js
$('.avatar').click(function() {

  $('.avatar').toggleClass("hey");
  if ($(".changebutton").is(':visible')){
    $(".changebutton").hide();
    $(".myButton").hide();
  }
  else {
    //$('.avatar').toggleClass("heyback"); // not sure if this was intended
    $(".changebutton").show();
    $(".myButton").show();
  };
});
```

```css
.hey {
  color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='avatar'>AVATAR</div>
<div class='changebutton'>changebutton</div>
<div class='myButton'>myButton</div>
```

There are tons of ways to optimize/extend this (like using a flag, or simply toggling like in adeneo's comment, etc), but without knowing more, just make sure you don't create listeners inside a listener callback functions.

Comment: toogleclass('hey') is irrelevent

Comment: I wonder how? on load the .changebutton and .myButton are always visible and if block is executed when you click them again else block is executed why you need toogle class here except for color change(which is pretty much nothing)?

Comment: How do you know OP is not doing a 180-degree 3D rotation on the Y-axis with a 1-second easy-in transition combined with a background gradient animation just by toggling that class?

Comment: Normal answer, as I said in the comments, @adeneo showed it can all be done by toggling, but I wasn't sure about the `heyback` thing, so I used the conditionals instead. And if OP had the toggleClass code in the original, it's not up to anyone else to decide about its relevancy (which is what the comment above tried to tell - I added a color change so you don't have to use Dev Tools to see whether the class has changed).